# How to fix Internal server error Flask nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, internal-server-error

Im having a problem with my Flask application
When I login to my account I sometimes get an internal server error and sometimes not. But then I get it later on another page. Is this due to my SQL requests?

App.py

```
from flask import *
import pymysql.cursors, os, hashlib
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from datetime import date

today = date.today()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'])
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

con = pymysql.connect(host='xxx', port=xxx, user='xxx', password='xxx', db='xxx')

def getLoginDetails():
    if 'email' in session:
        loggedIn = False
        username = ''
        firstname = ''
        uuid = ''
        function = ''
    else:
        loggedIn = True
        with con.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute('SELECT username, uuid, firstname, function FROM users WHERE email="' + session['email'] + '"')
            username, uuid, firstname, function = cur.fetchone()
        con.close()
    return (loggedIn, username, uuid, firstname, function)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'email' in session:
        loggedIn, username, uuid, firstname, function = getLoginDetails()
        with con.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM unban ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3")
            unbans = cur.fetchall()
        con.close()
        with con2.cursor() as cur2:
            cur2.execute("SELECT * FROM data")
            data = cur2.fetchall()
        con2.close()
        return render_template('index.html', loggedIn=loggedIn, username=username, uuid=uuid, firstname=firstname, function=function, unbans=unbans, data=data)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    if 'email' in session:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else:
        return render_template('login.html', error='')

@app.route('/loginForm', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def loginForm():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
        if is_valid(email, password):
            session['email'] = email
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
            error = 'Verkeerde inlog gegevens.'
            return render_template('login.html', error=error)

def is_valid(email, password):
    with con.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(f"SELECT email, password from users")
        data = cur.fetchall()
        for row in data:
            if row[0] == email and row[1] == hashlib.md5(password.encode()).hexdigest():
                return True
            return False
    con.close()

@app.route('/bans')
def bans():
    if 'email' in session:
        loggedIn, username, uuid, firstname, function = getLoginDetails()
        with con.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM unban ORDER BY id DESC")
            unbans = cur.fetchall()
        con.close()
        return render_template('bans.html', loggedIn=loggedIn, username=username, uuid=uuid, firstname=firstname, function=function, unbans=unbans)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Nginx config:

```
server {
        server_name staff.buddiedj.nl;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                client_max_body_size 5M;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/staff.buddiedj.nl/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/staff.buddiedj.nl/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = staff.buddiedj.nl) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        server_name staff.buddiedj.nl;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Error in webpage:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

Error in nginx log

```
2020/06/14 00:04:25 [warn] 4442#4442: could not build optimal proxy_headers_hash, you should increase either proxy_headers_hash_max_size: 512 or proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size
```

What could be the cause of this problem? And how can I solve it? I've been working on it for a few days but it still doesn't work. At first I was thinking about multiple open SQL connections but I've already adjusted that. And I do have it on my nginx server, but not on localhost

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to be more specific `an internal server error`. What's the error?

Comment: I added the error to the information! Thanks

Comment: You need to get the error and stack trace that's reported from the server code (i.e. in the console where the server is running).

Comment: How do you mean, exactly? I don't get it wrong if I run it on nginx as far as I know? (First time I really deploy an app to the internet so I apologize if I ask weird questions)

Comment: Have you tried doing what nginx suggests, and add the `proxy_headers_hash_max_size` directive to your nginx configuration? See also [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/419847/nginx-setting-server-names-hash-max-size-and-server-names-hash-bucket-size).

Comment: I did, nothing changed

Comment: ```def getLoginDetails():
    if 'email' in session:
        
    else:
        loggedIn = True
    return (loggedIn, username, uuid, firstname, function) ```  is your session valid on email found. If so then render results(sql0 is what would be appropriate here

Comment: Its stillnot working, anyone else that has a fix for this?